# Calling functions from C (example.i) in TCL code

Tags: c, interface, tcl

I have a file called `example.i` that allows the calling of a number of C functions.

Is it possible to call these functions from my TCL code? I have seen some ways to call C functions from TCL but I found them very hard to understand or incomplete, at least for a TCL rookie such as myself. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty extensively documented already.

See here [hello_world](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Hello+World+as+a+C+extension) and here [SWIG](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Swig) for example.

Comment: Links dead, updated.

Comment: @JayM Good job. Although I suspect OP is long gone...

Comment: SE Is a QA system, not a 1st line support msg board. The answers supplied are not just for the OP but to capture knowledge of others as the answers change over time.

Answer (score 0):

The .i suffix suggests you are generating an interface using **swig**.  If so, swig has a -tcl option that should generate code for an extension you can load into Tcl - see [Swig page on the Tcl wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/719)